# solve_ivp returned solution is too large and takes too long

Tags: python, scipy, physics, differential-equations

I'm solving a set of equations for `phi, psi` using the following:

```
def _derivs(self, t, y):
    """
    A function that defines the diff-equationS that are to be solved:
     1. I * phi_ddot = tau_motor - tau_drag.
     2. I * psi_ddot = F_tot x R - kappa * psi - gamma * psi_dot
    """

    phi, phi_dot, psi, psi_dot = y
    phi_ddot = 0.02 - phi_dot * np.abs(phi_dot)
    f_lift = 1.7 * phi_dot * np.abs(phi_dot)
    f_drag = - 0.8 * phi_dot * np.abs(phi_dot)
    f_tot = np.sqrt(f_drag ** 2 + f_lift ** 2)
    psi_ddot = f_tot - psi - psi_dot
    dy_dt = [phi_dot, phi_ddot, psi_dot, psi_ddot]
    return dy_dt

phi0, phi_dot0, psi0, psi_dot0= 0, 2e-4, 0, 2e-4
start_t, end_t = 0,0.2
sol = solve_ivp(_derivs,t_span=(start_t, end_t),y0=[phi0, phi_dot0, psi0, psi_dot0])
```

The constant prefixes like `1.7` and `-0.8` shouldn't be taken seriously here (I calculate them differently, but this is irrelevant to the problem)

The problem is that the solver takes a few minutes to finish, and the returned solution `sol.y` is unreasonably long (more than 100k values). When I only solve for `phi`, on the other hand, the solver returns a much shorter solution, which makes sense.

Any idea what could be the problem here?

Comment: I ran your code without any modifications. The output is `y: array([[0.00000000e+00, 4.82710767e-06, 2.72988850e-04, 4.39935215e-04],
       [2.00000000e-04, 4.82786691e-04, 3.31006825e-03, 4.19876577e-03],
       [0.00000000e+00, 2.80790937e-06, 2.87378055e-05, 3.61294157e-05],
       [2.00000000e-04, 1.97175466e-04, 1.70102660e-04, 1.62450715e-04]])` for `t: array([0.        , 0.01413942, 0.15553364, 0.2       ])`. I can't repeat the problem you encountered

Comment: What are your versions of python and scipy, or does the problem persist if you update scipy to the current version? You might want to set error tolerances, the default `atol=1e-3` might be too large for your system. The rule-of-thumb is `atol=scale*rtol` with a scale that is a typical magnitude for the components over time.